# Check my proof: What determinants are possible for integer matrices whose inverses are also integer matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I claim this is an adequate proof, but would appreciate criticism.

Trivially, we can see that this would be true for the special linear group ($|det(A)|=1$).

For the inverse condition to be true, the determinant must divide each element of the cofactor matrix, where $c_{ij} = (-1)^{i+j}M_{ij}$. Thus $det(A)|M_{ij} \forall i,j $ .

As the $(n-1)$st minor is a diagonal element, the "multiplicative trace" of $A$ must divide each element in the cofactor matrix.

Thus any integer determinant for A is attainable.

Comment: The proof is not correct. It is true that if the inverse of an integer matrix $A$ has integer entries, the determinant of $A$ must divide every entry of the cofactor matrix. Your corollary from this is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiplicative trace"?

Comment: @TomAriel Thanks for pointing me to that error. I thought about it for the rest of the day, I think I've come to something reasonable, which I posted below.

Comment: @user1551  I imagined it would be obvious I meant the product of the diagonal. Is that not obvious, or otherwise bad style?

Answer (score 1):

I appear to have made an incorrect move regarding the minor.

I made the incorrect assumption that the minor preserves the diagonal of $A$, removing diagonal elements only one at a time.

We may recursively take minors of any matrix until arriving at a 1x1 matrix of any arbitrary element in $A$ (not only diagonal elements, as I had earlier assumed).

As $det(A)|M_{ij}$, and $M_{ij}|M_{ik,jl}, k\ne i, l\ne j$, and so on up to each single element matrix, $det(A)|a_{ij}$, that is, the determinant divides every element of $A$.

Suppose $A:n\times n;$ $|det A | \ne 1$. Let $|c|\ne1$ be the largest such element dividing each element in $A$. We may multiply each row in A by $c^{-1}$ to get $A'$ with $\det A'=c^{-n}\det A=1$,with the latter given by the condition that $c$ is the largest possible element.

Possible determinants for $A(\mathbb F^{n\times n})$ are therefore $c^n$ $\forall c\in\mathbb F$. In the case of integer matrices, $c\in\mathbb Z$, but then $c$ does not divide the elements of  $A^{-1}$. Therefore $|c|=1$ and A belongs to the special linear group.

Comment: If $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are integer matrices, then $\det A$ and $\det A^{-1}$ are integers. Since $\det A^{-1} = 1/\det A$, this means that $\det A$ and its reciprocal must both be integers. This forces $\det A = \pm 1$.

Comment: @Bungo, heh, I just remembered I was working over the integers and not an arbitrary field, a couple seconds before you posted. Thanks

Comment: Moreover, as can be seen by expressing $A^{-1}$ in terms of the cofactor formula, *every* integer-valued member of the special linear group has an integer-valued inverse, so this completely characterizes the set of solutions: an integer-valued matrix has an integer-valued inverse if and only if it's a member of the special linear group.